# json object from javascript nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm using a nested array with the following structure:

```
arr[0]["id"] = "example0";
arr[0]["name"] = "name0";
arr[1]["id"] = "example1";
arr[1]["name"] = "name1";
arr[2]["id"] = "example2";
arr[2]["name"] = "name2";
```

now I'm trying to get a nested Json Object from this array

```
arr{
 {
 id: example0,
 name: name00,
 },
{
 id: example1,
 name: name01,
 },
{
 id: example2,
 name: name02,
 }
}
```

I tought it would work with `JSON.stringify(arr);` but it doesen't :( 
I would be really happy for a solution.

Thank you!

Comment: The structure you are using is invalid JS.

Comment: `nested Json Object` makes little sense

Comment: Also the desired JSON output is invalid JSON.

Comment: What error do you get when you try `JSON.stringify()`. Can you show us a complete example code snippet?

Comment: Obligatory [*"There's no such thing as a JSON object"*](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you are starting with a 2d array that looks like `[[ "example0", "name00"],
["example1", "name01"],
["example2", "name02"]]` ?

Comment: Your desired *output* is not a valid JavaScript object structure. You can't have an object with inner properties that aren't assigned to a key. It looks like you already have what you need. Why is the initial array not sufficient?

Comment: thats right max

Comment: @betterel but that's not what you've shown in your question. It looks to me like you are starting with this ~ `[{id: 'example0', name: 'name0'}, {id: 'example1', name: 'name1'}, {id: 'example2', name: 'name2'}]`

Comment: it should be a 2d array like max said, by using JSON.stringify on my array I don't get any errors but console.log just shows an empty array

Comment: The code at the top of your question **is not a 2d array**. It is an array of objects, each containing an `id` and `name` property. If this differs from reality, then you **need to update your question**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are starting out with an array that looks like this, where each subarray's first element is the id and the second element is the name:

```
const array = [["example0", "name00"], ["example1", "name01"], ["example2", "name02"]]
```

You first need to map it to an array of Objects.

```
const arrayOfObjects = array.map((el) => ({
  id: el[0],
  name: el[1]
}))
```

Then you can call `JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects)` to get the JSON.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make a valid array:

```
arr = [
 {
 id: 'example0',
 name: 'name00',
 },
{
 id: 'example1',
 name: 'name01',
 },
{
 id: 'example2',
 name: 'name02',
 }
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Note that I am assigning the array to a variable here. Also, I use `[]` to create an array where your original code had `{}`.

Comment: Seems OP already has this structure. Also, you need to quote your strings

Comment: @Phil The original question is close to this structure, but not exactly the same. See my edit that explains the changes.

Comment: That code block right at the top of the question. It looks exactly like what you've got in your answer (except with strings)

Comment: @Phil When I first posted my answer, the first block of code was not even correct JavaScript. The current edit is incomplete, so it is still difficult to tell for sure where the problem is.

Comment: @Phil Since the OP's code does not work, he cannot have exactly the same as what I have here now that I have fixed the quoting issue.

Comment: I completely agree with you. OP's question is confusing and obviously does not match what they actually have